# How to check wether an URL already has a parameter inside it?

Tags: php, append

Using PHP I need to check whether an URL I am appending information to already has a parameter or not.

So if the URL is

```
http://test.com/url?a=1
```

I would need to add on &b=2, ie

```
http://test.com/url?a=1&b=2
```

However if the URL was

```
http://test.com/url
```

I would need to append

```
http://test.com/url?b=2
```

Is it possible to check for this within PHP? In summary I need to attach the b=2 parameter using the correct separator character ("?" if there was none in the existing link or "&" if there is already a "?" in the existing link).

Answer (score 3):

Do not check but assemble a new one
use $_GET array and http_build_query() function

Comment: ok thanks, interesting idea! I've not used _GET array before, how would I use it bearing in mind I don't know how many parts it may split the URL into?

Comment: @kitenski you don't have to care. It will be done automatically.

Comment: ok thanks, and please excuse my ignorance, but could you give me an example of how _GET array would work please??

Comment: @kitenski is it for the current being processed or for the some URL  stored in a variable? if latter - use Dennis' answer

Comment: It's already stored in a database, so I can read it into a variable, hence will use Dennis' anaswer, thanks alot for the prompt follow up

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).
Then use `parse_str()` to get the query pieces, modify the array and use http_build_query() to recreate the query string.

Answer (score 0):

With this function, you can call `set('b', 2)` or set multiple values at once with `set(array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3))`.

```
function set($name, $value='', $vars='') {
    if (!$vars) $vars = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    parse_str($vars, $a);
    if (!is_array($name)) $name = array($name => $value);
    foreach ($name as $k => $v) {
        $a[$k] = $v;
        if ($v === '') unset($a[$k]);
    }
    $q = '';
    foreach ($a as $k => $v) $q .= ($q ? '&' : '') . $k . '=' . $v;
    return $q ? '?' . $q : '';
}
```